# DQN behaves differently on different computers

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, reinforcement-learning

I have a more or less standard implementation of DQN solving the Atari "Breakout" (from Coursera Reinforcement learning course), that behaves totally different on different computers:

- on my Laptop it converges **each time** I run it
- on Coursera and Google Colab servers it **never** converges!

#### I use

- Python3
- Tensorflow
- Kerass (only for Conv2D, Flatten and Dense layers)

I already spend some two weeks on the issue without any progress :(

#### I already checked:

- The versions:

  - Python: same (3.6.7)
  - Tensorflow: same (tested with 1.4.0 and 1.5.0)
  - numpy: same up the bugfix number (1.16.2 vs 1.16.3)
- Random seeds
- float32 vs float64: I always pass `dtype=np.float32` to each np.array and tf.placeholder call.
- CPU/GPU

  - My laptop, that **converges**, uses old CPU (that limits Tensorflow to <= 1.5.0)
  - On Coursera server, that **never converges**: CPU?
  - On Google Colab server, that **never converges**: GPU

#### My questions here are:

- What may be cause of the different behavior?
- How such problems get debugged?
- What can I also do/check to finally find the problem?

### Update: All the code (incl. hyperparameters, env, ...) is exactly the same.

Comment: There are so many stochastic elements in an RL algorithm(hyperparameters, randomness in the environment, randomness in NN gradient steps) there is almost no chance the results of a DQN would be the same for two separate runs. Its not a problem as long as you get a good result on the environment run though. If you are sure you have implemented the algorithm correctly, tune the hyperparameters in the other environment. Check the reward over time to see if the algorithm is learning in the other two.

Comment: Do you set all seeds? (numpy, tf, gym (not sure if keras has, I don't use it) Also, tf behavior is different between CPU and GPU.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you run a certain version of your code with a given hyper-parameter values. Then, you need to fix random seed in the beginning of your code for `tensorflow` (e.g. `tf.set_random_seed(1)`), for `numpy` (e.g. `np.random.seed(1)`) and for random, if you use it.

Additionally, you have to have same version of tensorflow on all you machines. I had a experience that even the forward pass between 1.3 and 1.8 resulted in two different outputs. Same check is required for `gym`.

Finally, you have to check with either cpu or gpu. You cannot compare the results of a cpu run with a gpu run.

If neither of these checks worked, I can check your `colab` code if you want to share it.

Comment: Thank you very much for the kind offer to check my code! I will follow all your recommendations and get back to you!